# Casting generic function type arguments in c#

Tags: c#, generics, casting, typecasting-operator

I have two generic functions that can take generic type arguments, and i have three main classes and lots of sub classes

Classes: `Base`, `Normal`, `Special`

Both `Special` and `Normal` inherit from `base`, `special` is a final class but `normal` has many child classes

My functions are as follows

```
public void doWork<T>() where T:Base
{
    list<T> = 
        typeof(T) == typeof(Special) ?
        (List<T>)Convert.ChangeType(GetObjectsSelectedFromSpecial(),typeof(List<T>)) : // this is very ugly
        (List<T>)GetObjectsSelectedFromNormal<T>(); // this will not compile
}
```

`GetObjectsSelectedFromSpecial` returns a list of `Special`, which is fine

`GetObjectsSelectedFromNormal<T>` looks like this, and can be passed any child of `Normal`

```
public List<T> GetObjectsSelectedFromNormal<T>() where T : Normal
{
    ...
    ExternalFunction<T>(); // this needs T to be of type `Normal`
    ...
}
```

but in the line

```
... : (List<T>)GetObjectsSelectedFromNormal<T>();
```

I get the error

> The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'myProject.GetObjectsSelectedFromNormal()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'T' to 'Normal'.

Is there a way to cast generic type arguments? not an object of type `T` but cast/convert/enforce-the-type-of `T` itself? Everywhere I've looked it is only talking about casting variables to and from `T`

Edit:
`Base`, `Normal` and `Special` are internal classes to a framework I do not have access to alter directly, so solutions involving altering the classes are not possible

Comment: GetObjectsSelectedFromNormal<T> T valid arguement for a method that requires a specific object type.

T in this case is only "Base" not a "Normal". That is likely why.

Comment: @MortenBork Okay, but i can guarantee `T` will be of type `Normal` at runtime... is there a way to tell c# that this code is fine? even something hacky? (I come from c++ and am not used to the language not trusting me)

Comment: why not just override `DoWork` in `Special`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'll edit my question to add this information i forgot to say, `Base` `Special` and `Normal` are internal classes to a framework i do not have access to - i cannot alter those classes (but i so strongly fell like i shouldn't need to)

Comment: well, a generic function with some type-checking like `typeof(T) == typeof(Special) ` contradicts the purpose of generics, which is "this function handles all types the same way, regardless on the actual `T`".

Comment: Anyway which code **are you allowed** to modify?

Comment: This looks really odd to me. Your `doWork` method takes any kind of `Base` type, yet inside there, there's a specialised call that uses `Normal`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere anything except the implementation of those classes, and `ExternalFunction<T>()`... but if you're saying this kind of type checking defeats the purpose then ill refactor the function into handling `normal` and `special` seperate. Thanks for the help, i think I'm still thinking of these functions too much like c++'s templates which are perhaps more suited to this kind of solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generic function that checks for a **specific** type isn´t really **generic**, is it? So instead of having a single method that only delegates the call to another method based on the actual type, just have different methods for different types in the first place:

```
public void DoWorkBase() { ... }
public void DoWorkNormal() 
{
    var list = GetObjectsSelectedFromNormal();
}
public void DoWorkSpecial() 
{ 
    var list = GetObjectsSelectedFromSpecial();
}
```